# Value of compileSdkVersion for Android P Developer Preview

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, android-p-developer-preview

What should be the value of:

```
compileSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion
```

I have downloaded and installed Android P Developer Preview SDK, System image and build tools.

I have tried "28" but it is showing this error:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the P preview:

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'

targetSdkVersion 'P'
```

See: https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html

Answer (score 6):

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 'P'
```

Comment: and what should be the libs version?

Answer (score 0):

`compileSdkVersion 'android-P'`

with

`targetSdkVersion 28`

Worked for me!

Comment: Question is for "Developer Preview" not for stable version.