# Unable to merge dex gradle build fail

Tags: android, gradle

Unable to build legacy android app. Whenever I tried to build it in Android studio 3.0.1 it throws the error below. I've tried various solutions available here in stack but to no avail. Appreciate any help in spotting misconfiguration or tips to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Error Code

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

This is the build configuration for the project.

```
app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.one"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
        implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.0'
        implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.0.2@aar'
        implementation files('src/main/libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
        implementation files('src/main/libs/commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar')
        implementation files('src/main/libs/core-2.2.jar')
        implementation files('src/main/libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


ProjectOne/gradle.build
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: change your `compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28"`

Comment: add `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'` to your dependencies and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment out these lines (I am not sure if this leads to dependencies confliction or unexpected errors):

```
   // implementation files('src/main/libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
   // implementation files('src/main/libs/commons-ssl-0.3.11.jar')
   // implementation files('src/main/libs/core-2.2.jar')
   // implementation files('src/main/libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
```

Edit this `compileSdkVersion 28` into `compileSdkVersion 'android-P'`.

Remove `buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"` in order to avoid version confliction. Gradle will know which suitable version to compile

One more thing, because your `minSdk` is >= 21, so you don't need to add this dependency

```
      implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

Comment: if i set the value to compileSdkVersion as 'android-P' it throws an error Failed to find target with hash string 'android-P'. Also I can't apply your suggestion to comment out those libs because they are being used in the app. I did try to comment them out and it gave me an error missing library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183406/value-of-compilesdkversion-for-android-p-developer-preview. Please check this. 'android-P' works for me in this case. Try clean and rebuild by gradle again.